# Generalized geometrical series and sums

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, approximation, estimation

I am looking for some information about series of the following form
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{P(n)},$$
where $P(n)\in\mathbb{Z}[n]$ and $x\in(0,1)$. I am interested also in their partial sums, i.e. $\sum_{n=a}^b x^{P(n)}$. I know that in general it is impossible to calculate it explicitly. I am looking for some list of such series, their asymptotics, estimations,approximations, theorems about convergence etc. Unfortunately, I didn't find any good source of such data. Where I can find some information ? Are some specific names of such a series which I can use to easily find them ?

Comment: It would really help if you tell *why* you need to know this, there might be additional information which would help to get a better answer

Comment: @YuriyS, I have few such a series (they come from physical considerations and are only a part of much longer symbolical calculations). I am trying to say something about my variables and the behaviour of these series (maybe) will help me (especially some estimations, approximations). I have some numerical tests but it would be also interesting to find some analytical properties.

Comment: I am an aficionado and I believe that maybe you can be interested in Csaba Sándor, *A note on a conjecture of Erdös-Turán*, INTEGERS: Electronic Journal of Combinatorial Number Theory **8** (2008), A30. It is a free access journal. I believe then that you need to set more conditions for your polynomials $P(n)$ to met the assumptions of such context (as you see from the Abstract). Good luck.

Comment: Let $f(x) = \sum_{n=2}^\infty x^{P(n)}$. Its [Mellin transform](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/280145/numerical-evaluation-of-some-series/280148#280148) is $\int_0^\infty f(e^{-t}) t^{s-1}dt = \Gamma(s) \sum_{n=2}^\infty P(n)^{-s} =  \Gamma(s)  \sum_{k=0}^\infty h_k(s) (\zeta(s+k)-1)$

Comment: @reuns, Mellin transform - my favourite tool :D - thanks, I will try to do something with this stuff.